# Django taggit not installing

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I'm trying to install django-taggit, but I'm getting this traceback error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 275, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1371, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 655, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 885, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 209, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 196, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/filipefr2/.pip/pip.log
```

I already tried to update setuptools with:

```
easy_install-2.7 -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the privileges needed to install the package (particularily to create that dir).

Either use root or (much better) try [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)